Different model in code than what is deployed
Using ChatGPT4o on Azure for additional security and GDPR compliance. Deployed the latest model version 2024-05-13. When we use that model in the code though it errors, with 'no existing resource.'
Only when we use the model shown in the playground code endpoint (2024-02-15-preview) does it work.
We want to use the latest model obviously. Can anyone explain this to us?
Deployed the current model. Expected to use that in the Python code. Only works with older model name however.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


Deployed the latest model version 2024-05-13. When we use that model in the code though it errors, with 'no existing resource.'

The above error occurs when you pass wrong API version, The version you given 2024-05-13 is model version and not an API version.
Deployment

As you said, the model shown in the playground code endpoint (2024-02-15-preview) which is API version will work and also you can refer this MS-Document for latest API reference.
Code:
In my below code I used latest API version is 2024-06-01
 from openai import AzureOpenAI
 
 client = AzureOpenAI(
   azure_endpoint = "https://xxxxx.openai.azure.com/", 
   api_key="2xxxxxxxxxx645f7283",  
   api_version="2024-06-01"
 )
 
 
 message_text = [{"role":"system","content":"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."},{"role":"user","content":"who is MS Dhoni?"}]
 
 completion = client.chat.completions.create(
   model="samplevenkat", # model = "deployment_name"
   messages = message_text,
   temperature=0.7,
   max_tokens=800,
   top_p=0.95,
   frequency_penalty=0,
   presence_penalty=0,
   stop=None
 )
 
 print(completion.choices[0].message.content)

Output:

Mahendra Singh Dhoni, commonly known as MS Dhoni, is a former Indian cricketer and captain of the Indian national team. Born on July 7, 1981, in Ranchi, Jharkhand, India, he is widely regarded as one of the greatest wicket-keeper batsmen and captains in the history of cricket.

Dhoni led India to numerous significant victories, including:

1. **ICC T20 World Cup 2007**: Under his captaincy, India won the inaugural ICC T20 World Cup.
2. **ICC Cricket World Cup 2011**: Dhoni played a pivotal role in India's victory, including scoring the winning runs in the final against Sri Lanka.
3. **ICC Champions Trophy 2013**: India won the Champions Trophy under his leadership, making him the only captain to have won all three major ICC trophies.

In addition to his international success, Dhoni has also been a key player in the Indian Premier League (IPL), leading the Chennai Super Kings (CSK) to multiple titles.

Dhoni is known for his calm demeanor, strategic acumen, and finishing ability in tight situations. He announced his retirement from international cricket on August 15, 2020, but continues to play in the IPL.

Reference:
python - Azure OpenAI - Resource not found - Stack Overflow by JayashankarGS.
